# Problem with git pull, doesn't merge all changes

Tags: git

My project uses react.js, I want to migrate to typescript.
My project has two branches "master" and "RoadToTS". The master branch has current changes on ts, in RoadToTS branch I make to migrate my components. But in parallel, my colleague makes some changes in the master branch.
For example.
Master branch:

```
-src
--components
---header
----header.jsx
```

RoadToTS:

```
-src
--components
---header
----header.tsx
```

I want to merge my branches but in Header component exist some updates which I wanna get. When I do "git pull origin master" I have a conflict on file which is irrelevant for the header component. When I solved the conflict, I do "git commit -m", and "git pull" is successfully ended.
But I didn't get current changes in Header component from master. When I try to do else "git pull", I get smth like this "Already up to date".
In this case "git pull doesn't work correctly". Why?

Comment: Could you check what the commit ID/hash of the last commit on master is and then check if that commit is on your local branch with: `git log | grep <commit_id>`?

Comment: Please can you [edit] your question to explain exactly the order you did things, and what commands you used? At the moment, you jump from "there are some updates I want to get" to "When I solved the conflict" - clearly there's something in between, where you did something, which caused a conflict, which you solved somehow ... all of which may be relevant to your problem. (Or it may not, but it's impossible to tell from this description.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing the following steps instead:

```
git checkout master
git pull
git checkout RoadToTS
git merge master
```

This should mean that your RoadToTS branch now has all the updated changes from master.